# playing videos with html5 on android device

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I'm building a mobile site and I'm having trouble playing video on android devices. I can get the video to play but find it erratic. Sometimes it causes the browser to crash, other times the controls aren't responsive. Most of my testing is on the Galaxy S3 and Nexus.

The code is a link that you can click to play the video.

```
<div id="player"></div>
<a href="#" onclick="DoNav('<?php echo $url; ?>');" title="Click to play video"> <?php echo $result_videos[$i]["camera_name"]; ?> </a>
```

The javascript/jquery mix (not very optimal, so maybe this is the problem):

```
function DoNav(theUrl)
{

// only add the player if it doesn't yet exist
if($('#myfileplayer').length == 0) {
    var mydiv = $("#player");
        var myvideo = $("<video id='myfileplayer' src='"+ theUrl + "' width='320' height='240' controls></video>");
           mydiv.append(myvideo);
} else {
   $('#myfileplayer').attr("src",theUrl); 
}

var video = document.getElementById('myfileplayer');
video.addEventListener('click',function(){
  video.play();
},false);

}
```

I'm not sure what else to debug here. Any ideas?

Comment: I would start with a static page that has a static video tag in it, and see if it plays ok.

Comment: @akonsu Tried that and yes it plays fine.

Comment: cool, then I would add "canplay" event listener on the video and there I would attach the click listener to make sure that I can click only when the video is ready.

Comment: why do you need the click event listener? you have controls on the video tag, which is sufficient to play the movie.

Comment: @akonsu Not sure I'm familiar with "canplay" - can you elaborate or provide a link. I guess I'm not googling correctly.

Comment: please see for example http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/ (section 5.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @akonsu he mentioned why I would even need the click event listener? Good point, I don't. I remove that and all the weird behavior is gone.

```
function DoNav(theUrl)
{

  // only add the player if it doesn't yet exist
  if($('#myfileplayer').length == 0) {
    var mydiv = $("#player");
    var myvideo = $("<video id='myfileplayer' src='"+ theUrl + "' width='320' height='240' controls></video>");
       mydiv.append(myvideo);
  } else {
     $('#myfileplayer').attr("src",theUrl); 
  }

}
```